# RegEx for capturing digits in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, regex-group, regex-greedy, regex-alternation

I am pulling in job numbers and matching them to data in a mysql database, then retrieving the matching data.

If my job number is `123456` then it matches up fine and I get results.
Some are `123-456` some are `12-text`, while some are `12-text-345`

```
$variable = $variable
```

I tried matching the variable but that's what's not effective.
I tried changing  the SQL within PHPMyAdmin and it doesn't even work smoothly there.
I googled and think I should be using RegExp. I tried. I can add a slash and make it work on individual items, however, I do not know where the hyphen will be amidst a massive array. It might be the third or fourth character.
I tried pregmatch but I don't think I know what I'm doing with that. 
I'm looking for a few lines of code to analyze a PHP variable and both detect and escape any meta characters if there are any. A tutorial link would be fine too, I appreciate any assistance

Comment: Posting your attempted code will benefit you getting answers quicker.

Comment: So are you saying that the job number entered isn't in the same format as the database or the other way round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, if we wish to only get the numbers, on way would be to collect our digits in a capturing group and then collect everything else, then replace it with just `$1`, with an expression similar to:

```
(\d+)|\D+
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(\d+)|\D+/m';
$str = 'text-12-text-345';
$subst = '$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo $result;
```

#### Output

```
12345
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/IgCaNC/1)

Comment: Why not just simply replace all the non digits with empty string, i don't think there any need of capturing group

Comment: Thanks Emma, I appreciate it